# Different CSS rules for different languages/modes (CodeMirroe)

Tags: javascript, css, codemirror

Is there a possibility to make [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) highlight different languages in [multi-mode](http://codemirror.net/mode/php/index.html) differently?
I want such classes to apply:

```
.cm-s-default .cm-string-html {color: blue;}
.cm-s-default .cm-string {color: #170;}
```

When [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) highlights the code, it leaves the same class names for the strings, comments and other objects in all languages, but I prefer to have them highlighted differently.

Answer (score 0):

There's no convenient way to do this currently, but with a bit of fiddling around you could wrap the inner XML mode to append a string like `"-html"` to all the token styles.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I don't even see where the code holding elements are manipulated within the CodeMirror modes. It rathre seems that they only parse strings and the main library decides where to append which class. I may be very wrong anyway.